# Web3 smart contract instance is not able to listen Transfer events

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I have a NFT deployed on the mainnet, and I want to listen any mint event by watching the Transfer event via web3js. But unfortunately I am not able to retrieve any Transfer event happening. But the thing is that, when I try to getPastEvents, I successfully retrieve the correct data so it is most likely not due to another part of the code.
Here is my relevant piece of code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const nodeClient = require('node-rest-client-promise').Client()
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x8d4B648F7fAB1c72d1690b42693fb7525ce3025e'
const projectId = process.env.INFURA_KEY
const etherscanKey = process.env.ETHERSCAN_KEY
const etherscan_url = `http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${CONTRACT_ADDRESS}&apikey=${etherscanKey}`


async function getContractAbi() {
  const etherscan_response = await nodeClient.getPromise(etherscan_url)
  const CONTRACT_ABI = JSON.parse(etherscan_response.data.result);
  return CONTRACT_ABI;
}

async function handleTransferEvent(event) {
  try{
    const fromAddress = event.returnValues.from
    const tokenId = event.returnValues.tokenId
    console.log("SOMEONE TRANSFERED NFT!")
    if(fromAddress == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
      console.log("Minted:\n", event.returnValues)
      /* Do stuff */
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log("ERROR WHILE HANDLING TRANSFER EVENT")
  }
}


const init = async () => {
  
  var web3 = new Web3('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/' + projectId)
  console.log("Connected to mainnet")
  
  const CONTRACT_ABI = await getContractAbi()
  console.log("Retrieved contract abi")

  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    CONTRACT_ABI, 
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS
  )

  contract.events.Transfer({})
  .on('data', handleTransferEvent)
  .on('error', console.error)

  console.log('Started listening minting events...')
}

init()
```

You can check the smart contract from https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d4b648f7fab1c72d1690b42693fb7525ce3025e#code

**EDIT:** I think problem might be related to calling listen event inside a function.

Comment: did you try not passing an empty object? (i use etherjs not web3 so i'm not sure if that could work)

Comment: yes I did, no change unfortunately :(